# RegEx mismatch in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Consider the following regex:

```
^[^-\s][a-zA-Z\sàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ\d!@#$\+%&\'*]{1,20}$
```

I did try it on https://regexr.com/ using as test `Collection '98` and matches.

I then did implement it in Node.js:

```
const myRegex = '^[^-\s][a-zA-Z\sàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ\d!@#$\+%&\'*]{1,20}$';

const name = 'Collection \'98';

if (!name.match(myRegex))
  console.log('NOK');
else
  console.log('OK');
```

However, it always prints `NOK`.

Why doesn't the validation work via app?

Comment: When a regex is passed as a string, backslashes are part of string escape sequences. If a string escape sequence is unknown, the backslash is omitted. Double them, or use regex literal notation.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your regex between slashes (`/`) instead of quotation marks `"` and it'll work:

```js
const myRegex = /^[^-\s][a-zA-Z\sàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ\d!@#$\+%&\'*]{1,20}$/;

const name = 'Collection \'98';

if (!name.match(myRegex))
  console.log('NOK');
else
  console.log('OK');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your codes, however it seems to me that your expression is correct and it works.

This snippets shows that it would return a match.

```js
const regex = /[^-\s][a-zA-Z\sàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ\d!@#$\+%&\'*]{1,20}/gm;
const str = `Collection '98`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

You can test/modify your expressions in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/UNODd6/1/).

[image]

---

It appears that you might have forgotten to add your expression in between two forward slashes, which you can simply fix it using `/expression/`.